# How to initialize more than one Solr instance using the same document class?

Tags: solrnet

In Solr I have two cores. The schema is the same but they have different documents.

Now I would like to have only one document class and initialize Solr for those two cores using the same document class.
For example:

Startup.Init("http://localhost:8983/solr/core1");
Startup.Init("http://localhost:8983/solr/core2");

But I get exception saying the key is already registered.

What is the solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/MultiCoreAccess):

> The built-in container (Startup) is currently limited to access multiple cores/instances with *different* mapped types.

So you can either contribute to the project to lift this limit, or switch to Windsor or StructureMap.